# Unable to run gauge test - connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: python, grpc-python, getgauge

I am developing some tests with gauge and python but on running specs i am getting connections error, I checked gauge error and find that grpc is opening connection on 65271 and error is thrown for port 65268.

Am i missing something (its my first try)?

```
19-01-2021 17:20:38.022 [python] [INFO] Python: 3.9.0
19-01-2021 17:20:38.022 [python] [DEBUG] Loading step implementations from C:\workspace\test_gauge\step_impl dirs.
19-01-2021 17:20:38.061 [python] [DEBUG] Starting grpc server..
19-01-2021 17:20:38.066 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Attempting to connect to grpc server at port: 65268
19-01-2021 17:20:38.067 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Successfully made the connection with runner with port: 65268
19-01-2021 17:20:38.067 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Validation started.
19-01-2021 17:20:38.075 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Validation completed.
19-01-2021 17:20:38.075 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Run started
19-01-2021 17:20:38.076 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Starting Html Report plugin
19-01-2021 17:20:38.083 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/python?l=python&p=html-report,java,python,screenshot&o=windows&a=amd64
19-01-2021 17:20:38.103 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Attempting to connect to grpc server at port: 65271
19-01-2021 17:20:38.103 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Successfully made the connection with plugin with port: 65271
19-01-2021 17:20:38.103 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Initialising suite data store.
19-01-2021 17:20:38.176 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Downloading https://downloads.gauge.org/plugin/screenshot?l=python&p=html-report,java,python,screenshot&o=windows&a=amd64
19-01-2021 17:20:38.217 [python] [CRITICAL] Exception occurred while loading step implementations from file: step_impl\webui\pages\login_page.py.
19-01-2021 17:20:38.220 [Gauge] [ERROR] Error Message: transport is closing
19-01-2021 17:20:38.220 [Gauge] [ERROR] Stacktrace: 
19-01-2021 17:20:38.220 [Gauge] [ERROR] Error Message: Runner is not Alive
19-01-2021 17:20:38.220 [Gauge] [ERROR] Stacktrace: 
19-01-2021 17:20:38.221 [html-report] [DEBUG] Transformed SuiteResult to report structure
19-01-2021 17:20:38.231 [Gauge] [ERROR] Error occurred while waiting for runner process to finish.
Error : exit status 1
19-01-2021 17:20:38.251 [Gauge] [DEBUG] Sending kill message to Html Report plugin.
19-01-2021 17:20:38.251 [html-report] [INFO] Successfully generated html-report to => C:\workspace\test_gauge\reports\html-report\index.html
19-01-2021 17:20:38.251 [html-report] [DEBUG] Done generating HTML report using theme from C:\Users\imrankhan\AppData\Roaming\gauge\plugins\html-report\4.0.12\themes\default
**19-01-2021 17:20:40.221 [Gauge] [ERROR] Failed to kill Runner: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:65268: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."**
19-01-2021 17:20:40.221 [Gauge] [INFO] Specifications:  0 executed  0 passed    0 failed    0 skipped
19-01-2021 17:20:40.222 [Gauge] [INFO] Scenarios:   0 executed  0 passed    0 failed    0 skipped
19-01-2021 17:20:40.222 [Gauge] [INFO] 
Total time taken: 145ms
19-01-2021 17:20:40.224 [Gauge] [INFO] Updates are available. Run `gauge update -c` for more info.
```

Answer (score 1):

As I looked into the logs and investigated a lot yesterday, it looks like the root cause of this issue is not gauge but my own scripts (so do you, I believe)

Note there is a key line "[python] [CRITICAL] Exception occurred while loading step implementations from file: step_impl\webui\pages\login_page.py." in your log, this is a sign to let you know that there are something wrong with your python scripts. If you don't figure out what's the matter with your python scripts, this issue will be there all the time.

On the surface, there is another issue that gauge runner blocks the detailed error of your python scripts (and mine) to be shown, which misleads us to point out the root cause to gauge runner but not the python scripts.

In a nutshell, gauge runner don't print out the detailed error logs for the python scripts, but there are.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the exactly same problem and raised a ticket in [github](https://github.com/getgauge/gauge/issues/1890). No lucky because no responses so far. This issue drives me crazy...